# Why are planets not self sufficient enough to support their population?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

It seems whenever the Trade Federation blockades a planet from trade, the inhabitants suffer greatly. Frequently running out of food and even water. This even happens on the home worlds of some species. Do these species rely so heavily on trade that they're unable to support their population without it? They must have developed their food and water sources and distribution networks over a long time. The planets are surely habitable enough to produce food and water since the species has lived and evolved there.

Comment: You aren't thinking big enough. Think of Coruscant for example, obviously they need momentous amounts of trade to sustain their population with food and water. Additionally, blockades aren't just meant to "starve out" a population, they are there to prevent trade which in turn would cripple economies. Even if a world's farmers could produce enough food, what would they be paid with? Eventually the entire economy of the planet would shatter, *including agriculture*.

Comment: I agree this could be the case with the planets that are all city, but there are planets that are not in the same situation. For example, The Clone Wars, season 3 episode 3. The Twi'lek planet is very simple, yet they are running out of food and water due to a blockade. Is the down-vote because I wasn't "thinking big enough" or because the question is unclear or not useful?

Comment: Wasn't my down vote...but you are ignoring the fact that the *reason that they place a blockade around a planet in the first place is to cripple the economy of the planet.* You can't just one moment be relying on off-world trade, and the next turn into a self-sustaining populace.

Comment: @NominSim Good point. I imagine planets that were self sufficient wouldn't of had a blockade placed around them, because it wouldn't have the desired effect.

Comment: Scary thought: a planet that needs to import millions of tons of food and water must be exporting a similar amount of sewage, if the biosphere is to be relatively stable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what drives the blockaded planet's economy. Once a planet becomes dependent on off-world income, it is just that: Dependent. A blockade could easily become a disaster.

Here are two examples:

If a planet has a booming economy from off-planet trade (let's say they export minerals and import food & water), it could easily become dependent on that income to sustain a population greater than the natural food & water supplies available on the planet. A sustained trade blockade would prevent the transfer of minerals into food supplies.

If a planet has a booming agricultural economy, a blockade could disrupt the off planet resources required to sustain it.

Comment: Agricultural economies may have economic collapse, but generally that doesn't lead to starvation on-world. It may lead to nationalization, but seldom starvation.

Comment: @aramis True...But logistics also come into play. You'd have storage issues. Where do you put the crops once your storage areas are full of produce that you can't sell?

Comment: you ferment them. Beer and wine are easy to make - and easy to store. wood alcohol provides ready fuel for heating, cooking, and power. A world scale is unlikely to lack the ability to package foods. As I said - starvation should NOT be an issue on agri-worlds. And on a world scale, monoculture is stupid - the natural range will result in too many potential pathogens spreading like wildfire. (Think potato famine.)

Comment: Damn Trade Guild.

Comment: @aramis - And what if you're relying on off-world supplies of food to feed your population? Nationalise whatever you like, if your planet is a primary producer of something non-edible then you're in big trouble if the food shipments stop coming.

Answer (score 11):

Any civilization rising to a specific level is overspecialized and dependent on infrastructure that is quite fragile.

If today we on earth lose, for example, access to just a couple of technologies (not necessarily obvious ones, e.g. some complicated chemical industries/processes) or specific rare materials (e.g. rare earths), within a year many of our supply processes would be irrevocably broken, and tons of people would die of starvation **even though we would have as much food-producing territory as today**.

And remember that only a handful of planets produce things such as droids, and probably other heavy equipment, or rare resources (as random SW examples, bacta and Tibana gas, though the latter is mostly used for weapons).

Answer (score 4):

When you have intragalactic trade worlds have the option to be come highly specialised, which is favourable for economic reasons (you end up with a monopoly in resource X, essentially). Even with worlds that could sustain plentiful harvests you might produce biofuel, or grassland for a particular animal etc.

As an analogy, consider on of the worlds from the 40K universe, which is on the same scale as the SW one I would say. They have entire worlds devoted to what is essentially [Kudzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKudzu_on_trees_in_Atlanta,_Georgia.jpg), it just covers the whole world, literally. This is for, I think biofuel.

If that planet had been blockaded, and the sector relied on it for biofuel, everyone would suffer. Kudzu is not good human food, and other planets need that fuel!

Yes, it could sustain itself, but the infrastructure just isn't there to accommodate that sort of change right away.